# Why does `ifelse()` behave differently than `if (cond) {...} else {...}`

Tags: r, if-statement

I was trying to generate uniform input arguments for a function (no matter if a user inputs numeric values or a unit object, the function should continue with a unit object), when I stumbled across this behaviour I cannot really explain right now:

```r
# case 1 ---
t <- 20

# expected output: 20 [°C]: fail
ifelse(inherits(t, "units"),
       t,
       units::as_units(t, "°C"))
#> [1] 20

# case 2 ---
t <- units::as_units(20, "°C")

# expected output: 20 [°C]: fail
ifelse(inherits(t, "units"),
       t,
       units::as_units(t, "°C"))
#> [1] 20

# case 3 ---
t <- 20

# expected output: 20 [°C]: everything OK
if (inherits(t, "units")) t else units::as_units(t, "°C")
#> 20 [°C]

# case 4 ---
t <- units::as_units(20, "°C")

# expected output: 20 [°C]: everything OK
if (inherits(t, "units")) t else units::as_units(t, "°C")
#> 20 [°C]
```

What am I missing? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `t` is an often used function and it's name should not be used as object names.

Comment: Valid point, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `ifelse` strips attributes. See `?ifelse`:

> **Warning**
>
> The mode of the result may depend on the value of test (see the
> examples), and the class attribute (see oldClass) of the result is
> taken from test and may be inappropriate for the values selected from
> yes and no.

In those cases, it's preferable to use `if`. Again from the documentation:

> Further note that `if(test) yes else no` is much more efficient and
> often much preferable to `ifelse(test, yes, no)` whenever `test` is a
> simple true/false result, i.e., when `length(test) == 1`.

Comment: Seems like a RTFM classic on my side. Thanks a lot for the clarification!